# Problems with events of speechSynthesis

Tags: javascript, events, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am working on a small app using SpeechSynthesisUtterance API.

I try to launch a small function betweens words (when they are enunciated) :

I  use **boundary** event : 

        `myWords.onboundary = function() {
        ...
        };`

But it doesn't work...Maybe i don't understand how works boundaries effect.

Please, can you help me ?

Thank you,

Thomas

Comment: Are you catching the event itself? Try printing out the event by doing
`myWords.onboundary = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        };`

Comment: "doesn't work" is an insufficient description of your problem

Comment: I already try you solution  Zach but there is nothing printed in my javascript console.  Actualy, no problems were detected. When i use another event as `onstart` or `onend` it works.  I just want to lauch my fonction after each words.

Answer (score 1):

[This boiled-down sample](http://jsbin.com/malopemefu/2/edit) illustrates the event not being fired.
And [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336769) discusses this problem, but came to the conclusion to use the "native voice" which didn't work for me on Linux or Windows...