# Track the word being spoken by SpeechSynthesis API

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, html5-audio, google-speech-api, speech-synthesis

I'm writing a software program that reads the text using the Web SpeechSynthesis API and show the word which is being spoken.

The speech API does have an `onboundary` event for doing this but it [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28753175/1031454) for most voices. So the only option is to track it approximately by calculating the time taken to speak each character and then track the word using it like this:

```js
function speak(text) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    let start = 0;

    msg.text = text;
    msg.onstart = (e) => {
      var evt = new CustomEvent('tts-play');
      window.dispatchEvent(evt);
      start = performance.now();
    };

    msg.onend = (e) => resolve(performance.now() - start);

    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
  });
}

function go() {
  let calibrate = 'Calibrating speech engine';
  let actualText = 'This is the text for which I want to track which word is spoken. As you can see, the text loses sync – Can you help me fix it?';
  speak(calibrate).then(ms => {
    let msPerChar = ms / calibrate.length;
    console.log("ms per char is ", msPerChar);

    let words = actualText.split(/\s+/);
    let track = () => {
      let delay = 0;
      for (let word of words) {
        setTimeout(() => $('#theWord').text(word), delay);
        delay += msPerChar * word.length;
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('tts-play', track());
    speak(actualText);
  });
}
```

```css
body, button {
font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Speech synthesis demo</p>
  <button onclick="go()">Start</button>
  <p>Spoken word: <span id="theWord"></span></p>
</div>
```

As you can see the text loses sync and the approach to track the word by calculating `msPerChar` needs some fine-tuning.

Any ideas how I can improve it?

Thanks.

P.S. Here is a jsfiddle for the same as it's easier to tinker with it: https://jsfiddle.net/superasn/7oyd0p4f/25/

Comment: It’s a really hard problem ; you’d need almost as much knowledge as actual speech synthesis requires. I’m afraid you’re out of luck, unless you can convince your users to switch to Safari.

Comment: yeah i figured but i'm willing to settle for an approximation. like just right now while playing with it adding this single line improved it by quite a lot: `delay += (word.match(/[,.?!]/g)||[]).length * 0.01;`. I'm looking for fine-tuning like these if possible.. https://jsfiddle.net/superasn/7oyd0p4f/37/

Comment: Are you sure onboundary doesn't work? The jsfiddle linked to in the other question gives many alerts.

Comment: @Frazer yes I confirmed it doesn't work for most voices (it does work for native voices only which sound very robotic)

Comment: P.S. maybe it has something to do with how many syllables a word has that improves sync? could it be something worth checking or it shouldn't matter?

Comment: Maybe you can use Safari, or one of the few native voices in other browsers, to collect empirical data on how long the most common words take to pronounce, and create a dictionary ? Maybe even some machine learning to create a lightweight model that doesn't require megabytes of code to apply ?

Comment: @Touffy that sounds like a good idea.. It will be a very interesting project too! thanks.